# Cannot convert value of type 'FetchedResults<Topic>' to expected argument type 'Set<Topic>'

Tags: core-data, swiftui

Calling `currentTopics(subject: subject, topics: topics)` throws an error: `Cannot convert value of type 'FetchedResults<Topic>' to expected argument type 'Set<Topic>'`.

This is the code:

```
func currentTopics(subject: Subject, topics: Set<Topic>) -> Set<Topic> {
var collected: Set<Topic> = []
    for topic in topics {
        if subject.topics!.contains(topic) {
            collected.insert(topic)
        }
    }
    return collected
}
```

And this is the declaration part:

```
struct TopicView: View {

    @State var subject: Subject
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)])
    private var topics: FetchedResults<Topic>
    
    ...
}
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you just change FetchedResults<Topic> to Set<Topic> ?

Comment: then another error is thrown: `Cannot convert value of type 'Set<Topic>' to specified type 'FetchedResults<NSManagedObject>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the signature should be

```
func currentTopics(subject: Subject, topics: FetchedResults<Topic>) -> Set<Topic> {
```

Comment: then the next problem shows up: `Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Set<Topic>' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'`

Comment: In my Foreach-loop casting to an array helped!! :) .... `Array(currentTopics(subject: subject, topics: topics))`

Comment: It is different error... if you cannot compile your code then provide it completely.